# how to apache druid or clickhouse

Tags: olap, clickhouse, olap-cube, druid

I‘m a new to clickhouse, and already read "druid vs clickhouse", but still don't know which situation can use clickhouse. I know they are good OLAP engines。

Druid is an excellent timing database。 At large data scale, it can provide ad-hoc aggregate queries，clickhouse too；

They have similar disadvantages, such as slow data writing。

Which engine should I do with OLAP？

Comment: look at this article - https://altinity.com/blog/tag/druid/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the great article https://leventov.medium.com/comparison-of-the-open-source-olap-systems-for-big-data-clickhouse-druid-and-pinot-8e042a5ed1c7

**Either your organization should have engineers who are able to read, understand and modify the source code of the chosen system, and have capacity to do that. Note that ClickHouse is written in C++, Druid and Pinot — in Java.**

Comment: No need to know Java or C++ - just use them.

Comment: I work in Altinity and my job is literally to read Clickhouse source code.

Comment: C++ code are generaly more performant and less memory overconsuming than vm language... druid and clickhouse are columndb, and is key performance for this type of usage...  i use in production clickhouse in place of prometheus and elk for differente monitoring usage with big size (elk cannot do with the same hardware) data with success...